# Updates to Ubuntu phone outside of the EU area

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

I would like to find out if an Ubuntu phone (specifically the MX4) will receive OS updates if the phone is in use outside of the EU, (Canada in this case). I am thinking about bringing in an Ubuntu powered MX4 from Europe, I have already researched if the phone will work with the carriers over here...it will... (unlocked of course).

So it really just comes down to finding out if OS updates are possible outside of the supported area. Would this be done OTA independent of the carriers? (this is the way Apple does it) or would I be required to download and install updates via a computer connection.

Any answers would be helpful.

Cheers

Comment: I assume, if you have an internet connection, WiFi, Mobile, then it will download the updates, no matter where you're from.

Answer (score 3):

Updates are over the Internet connection. So, WiFi or mobile Internet will do.

It's similar to how Ubuntu-for-desktop is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Ubuntu phone owner in Australia, purchased in Europe. All updates are running perfectly, same with mobile GSM network including 3G data.